# .NET Response.Write large HTML string, strips/breaks the content of SCRIPT tags

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a situation where an HTML content including javascript is sent to my script via an encoded querystring. On the receiving .NET page, I need to response.clear and write the querystring to the browser.

Everything gets written fine, except the contents of the script tags seem empty on Chrome Inspector.

[image]

When I check the page source, they are there but highlighted in red color[image]

Does anybody know what kind of sorcery this is?

I have tried

```
response.write(html)
```

and also

```
Dim html As String = Request.QueryString("html")
Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)

Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.Clear()
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length)
Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

but I had the same result. Is this some kind of security implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input string for non-printable characters that are not spaces. You may not be able to see those in the output, but the parser in the browser could generate a syntax error since they are not valid whitespace characters. You will have to check the raw bytes (around the code you are seeing the errors).

Also, you might be reaching the maximum length of the query string. It differs from browser to browser.

**Internet Explorer**

> RFC 3986 also states there is no limit, but indicates the hostname is
>   limited to 255 characters because of DNS limitations (section 2.3.3).
>   Microsoft states that the maximum length of a URL in Internet Explorer
>   is 2,083 characters, with no more than 2,048 characters in the path
>   portion of the URL.

**Chrome and Firefox**

No official documentation, but testing concluded that the limit was around 64K

*However, I would like to state that what you are doing is a huge security risk. You should never just render out the whole query string willy-nilly.*

Comment: Aye, I know, its an HTML response from the banking system in a country that shows a page where you have to enter a PIN number sent to your registered cellphone so you can use your debit card for online purchases. There is nothing I can do about it... As a remedy, I am saving the HTML to a file and redirecting to that file, which works fine but is not enough to let me sleep.  Its not the lenght, the content is all there in the source but it has those red demonic marks which I have never seen before.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. That's interesting. I don't think I understood your question fully the first time. I wonder if you are getting some un-printable characters? Can you look at the byte array or your content on your server? Before you stream it out? Look at that specific area of the markup and see if there are any characters that aren't spaces.

Comment: Yeah, it was weird empty characters. Thanks Matt

Comment: Ok then. Good to know.